# Recurring fraction to decimal on BigDecimal

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal

There are many ways to convert a rational number into a decimal with a recurring part (in other words, `10/3=3.(3)`, where `(3)` indicates that it repeats forever).  But these only work if the numerator and denominator are integers.  What can we do if the numerator or denominator is a double?  For example, how can we find that

```
1/0.3 = 3.(3)
```

UPDATE: 
This works but only for int numbers.

http://www.programcreek.com/2014/03/leetcode-fraction-to-recurring-decimal-java/

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? Show your input and desired output. And show us that your tried to solve your problem yourself before asking.

Comment: I want to make a division 1/0.3 and instead of getting 3.33333333333~ would like to detect the recurring fraction and display in a rouded form like 3.(3)

Comment: That's simple. You need to convert 0.3 into 3/10 before you make a division and then use rational math.

Comment: Clarified the problem

Comment: @talex it could be any double value like 1/0.3452. So if after that division we detect any recurrence it should be marked. In other words if the result of the division is 4.1212121212~ it should be noted as 4.(12).
If the result is 4.1212 it should stay that way. 

Another example: if you have a decision 5/0.2345 or whatever .. and the result is 0.11 is should display 0.11 but if the result is 0.1111111~
it should display 0.(1). Hope that clarifies the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let split the problem in two pieces:

- Convert `1/0.3` to `N/M` form
- Convert `N/M` to `a.b(c)` form

**Lets convert `0.3` to `M/N` form** (which give us `3/10`).

```
    String input = "123.456";
    String[] parts = input.split("\\.");
    String whole = parts[0];
    String fraction = parts[1];

    int wholeInt = Integer.parseInt(whole);
    int fractionInt = Integer.parseInt(fraction);
    int multiplier = pow10(fraction.length());
    int n = wholeInt * multiplier + fractionInt;
    int m = multiplier;

    System.out.println(n + "/" + m);
```

I used function `pow10` which simply returns 10 power input.

**Now we need divide `1` by `10/3`** it is easy `N1/M1` divided by `N2/M2` it is simply `(N1*M2)/(N2*M1)`.

We get our result in form `N/M` now (we also need to normalize it by dividing both part by `GCD(N, M`)

**Now we ready to solve main problem.**

First of all get whole part

```
    int whole = n/m;
```

then find fraction and repeating part

```
    int current = n%m;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    List<Integer> controlSet = new ArrayList<>();
    while((!controlSet.contains(current))){
        int currentDigit = current *10 / m;
        sb.append(currentDigit);
        controlSet.add(current);
        current = current *10 - m * currentDigit;
    }
    String fraction = sb.toString().substring(0, controlSet.indexOf(current));
    String repeat = sb.toString().substring(controlSet.indexOf(current));
```

Here we just divide in loop getting result number by number.

Main trick then number starts to repeat when we meet `current` that we already use.

Now you need to take all parts together. Implement `GCD` (lots of implementation over internet).

Comment: `int denominator = BigDecimal.TEN.pow( bd.scale()).intValue();
  int nominator = bd.unscaledValue().intValue();
  System.out.println(nominator + "/" + denominator);`